# Using PHP if within an array and increasing value+1 to a limit

Tags: php, arrays

I am using multiple IF statements and like to know how i would put these into an array.

the IF Statements

```
if ($totalEXP < $l1) echo "1";
if ($totalEXP < $l2) echo "2";
```

As you can see there the same apart from $l1 and the final echo
i would be using around 100 IF statements, Is there a way to put this in an array to save alot of coding?

I know i should be using the ELSEIF statement

```
<?php
if ($totalEXP < $l1) {
    echo "1";
} elseif ($totalEXP < $l2) {
    echo "2";
} else {
    echo "MAX";
}
?>
```

but for simplicity reasons i decided the route i had taken.

Sadly i havent tried much to get this working because i dont know if its even possible.

Comment: You have 100 variables from `$l1` to `$l100`?

Comment: @KingKing i understand that too

Comment: I suppose how you could go about this, if you know what these `$l1` through `$ln` variables are named, you could simply put them into an array , e.g. `$limits = [$l1,$l2,...,$ln];`, you could then have a function take in the $totalEXP value and the $limits array, looping through each until you get to a value where it is false. If you get to the last value, and it is still not false, return "MAX"

Comment: Maybe you should make use of a mathematical function (XP in games is often calculated potentially) and use  `%` modulus in a short method. [Example of XP formula in World of Warcraft.](http://www.wowwiki.com/Formulas:XP_To_Level)

Comment: yes i will have each $lx is a value, at present i only got up to $l4 but this will increase. @DanFromGermany could you link me to a example

Comment: @thenashone I added a rather valuable note to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course.

You put your level data in an array

```
$levels = array(
    1 => $l1,
    2 => $l2,
    ...
);
```

And then loop

```
$pleyer_level = 1;
foreach($levels as $level => $xp)
    if($totalEXP > $xp)
        $player_level = $level;
```

It is also smart to put a break in loops when you know their job is done so you don't iterate pointlessly

```
$pleyer_level = 1;
foreach($levels as $level => $xp)
    if($totalEXP > $xp)
        $player_level = $level;
    else
        break;
```

Comment: Oh thank you magic code fairy, I really didn't want to type my comment out.

Comment: I think the array can be defined simplier as `array(1=> $l1, $l2, ...)` (the index will be increased automatically). Also that's just my idea about defining that array, I personally think it's not really necessary.

Comment: @Jhecht did it ever occur to you that I may have not read the comments? Being a dick about something so minor speaks much of your character and you should be aware of that.

Comment: @KingKing that is true, but I wrote it like this because it's good practice to see the keys if they matter. For example if the array is defined as `level => xp` and `xp` is hardcoded, if you want to change some level's xp in future and you don't see the keys explicitly it's going to take longer than it should. However it looks like the OP is using variables and not hardcoding values in the array, so it's up to them to decide how to define it.

Comment: Wasn't being a DICK, genuinely didn't want to type the code out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best approach, but you could run the `if` statements in a `for` loop.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) // i increases every new loop
{
    if ($totalEXP < ${l$i}) // ${l$i} corresponds to $l1, $l2, $l3 and so on
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `$totalEXP < ${"l$i"}` your code may generate a syntax error.